# Audio Start Delay For The First Time - ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I am creating an application with five buttons. When I click on each button each audio will play. It is working. Now my problem is when I click first button audio play with 1 second delay(App stuck for 1 second) and play. Next time clicks a button  audio play without any delay. What could be the issue here?

I am using the following code to play an audio

```
var currentAudio = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample_audio", ofType: "mp3")!));
 currentAudio!.stop()
currentAudio!.currentTime = 0
 currentAudio!.play();
```

Please someone help me to finds this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AVAudioPlayer's `.prepareToPlay()` method to [preload the player's buffers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/prepareToPlay), it will increase AVAudioPlayer's performance (faster start).

The idea is to prepare the player some time before actually playing it:

```
currentAudio?.prepareToPlay()
```

then later, in your play function, it will start immediately:

```
currentAudio?.play()
```

Comment: It is working. But wherever I use this currentAudio?.prepareToPlay() code in that place there is a delay.  Is it anyway to use this same code without affecting UI?. +1 for your answer

Comment: I found a solution I am using background threads for this code. It is working. Is it correct? If correct then please update your answer maybe it will help others.